# Matplotlib pie autotexts color change issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to modify the color of autotexts .i.e. autopct. I'm getting the following error: "AxesSubplot' object is not iterable". 
Could you please assist me on this?

```
_, _, autotexts = df_spark["Record_count_check"].value_counts() \
                     .sort_index(ascending=False) \
                     .plot(kind='pie', y="Record_count_check", figsize=(10, 10),
                           legend=True, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90,
                           shadow=False,colors=['green','red'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.plot` returns an axes, so you cannot assign this to more than one value.

```
ax = df.plot( ... )
```

In order to get the texts, either use matplotlib

```
_, _, autotexts = plt.pie( ... )
```

or iterate over the texts in the axes

```
ax = df.plot( ... )
for text in ax.texts:
    # do something
```